# order of elastic search term(s)

Tags: elasticsearch

Curious, is it possible for elastic search to ignore word order, meaning that this search term:

```
hello world
```

returns the same results as this:

```
world hello
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch uses a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) if no analyzer is specified. This will tokenize the data (`"world hello"`) as

```
GET /_analyze

{
  "analyzer" : "standard",
  "text" : "world hello"
}
```

Tokens generated will be -

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "world",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "hello",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

Now when you search for `"hello world"` using a [match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html), this will search for documents having `title` field as `hello` OR `world`.

So this will match all the documents having `"hello world"` OR `"world hello"`

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "title":"world hello"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "hello world"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67225620",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.5753642,
        "_source": {
          "title": "world hello"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**NOTE: If you want that the order of the terms should be maintained, then you should use [match_phrase query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html) OR some different analyzer instead of `standard`**

Comment: amazing thanks. I knew it must be possible ... using a match query with an OR is obviously too sensitive ....